# Is not "$(this)", remove class?

Tags: javascript, scroll

Hi Guys:> I have this code that adds class "hover_triangle" to the div when it is on focusing part of the screen. I want to remove this class"hover_triangle" while it is not on the focusing part of the screen. Like to do same as script does, but remove this child item class when object was scrolled down. Hope someone can help me with this task. Thanks!

```
var $ = jQuery;


function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.jail-app-j-s-3-work').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
         !$(this).children('.bg').addClass('hover_triangle');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) for this like:

```
$('.jail-app-j-s-3-work').each(function() {
  $(this).children('.bg').toggleClass('hover_triangle', isScrolledIntoView(this));
});
```